# Razor: How to fill a textarea?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textarea, razor

I feel stupid asking this question, but I'm totally blank here :)

In my controller i have this:
ViewBag.TextareaHTML = "**test**"

How do I in my view fill my...

... with this ViewBag.TextareaHTML value?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@Html.TextArea("name", (string)ViewBag.TextareaHtml)

Comment: Thanks ... didn't even think of that :) !!